# CSS/HTML: Hover image, animate text not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to slide the text `{ transform: scale(1.3) translate(0px, 40px); }` while I am hovering the image, (with `class="img"`), but I don't know why this is not working.

```css
.img {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  border-radius: 85px;
}

.img:hover {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.3) translate(0px, -80px);
  z-index: 100;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.525);
  border-radius: 85px;
}

.caption {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -150px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.img:hover .caption {
  transform: scale(1.3) translate(0px, 40px);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="games/tictactoe.html"><img id="picture" class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="TicTacToe"></a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 class="gametitle">Tic Tac Toe</h3>
        <h2>Game for two players</h2>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="games/battleship.html"><img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="battleShip"></a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 class="gametitle">Battle Ship</h3>
        <h2>Game for two players</h2>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="games/pythagoreantable.html"><img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="pythagoreantable"></a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 class="gametitle">Pythagorean Table</h3>
        <h2>Tool</h2>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I think the string **".img:hover .caption"** is wrong, I tried in other ways but no one worked.
Thanks for the help

Comment: You are trying to do something that is not possible to achieve only with css and with your html structure. I you want to do so, you will need to make it with js or jQuery. `:hover`element will work on sibling at best. But here you are trying to modify a parent sibling.

Comment: I know but my teacher told us to make it without js

Comment: Ok then yeah as the good answer. You must do it on parent of image at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule selector `.img:hover .caption` won't find work because `.caption` is not a child of `.img`.

A simple solution would be to use the `li` as the hover target:

```css
.img {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  border-radius: 85px;
}

li:hover .img {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.3) translate(0px, -80px);
  z-index: 100;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.525);
  border-radius: 85px;
}

.caption {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -150px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

li:hover .caption {
  transform: scale(1.3) translate(0px, 40px);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="games/tictactoe.html"><img id="picture" class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="TicTacToe"></a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 class="gametitle">Tic Tac Toe</h3>
        <h2>Game for two players</h2>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="games/battleship.html"><img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="battleShip"></a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 class="gametitle">Battle Ship</h3>
        <h2>Game for two players</h2>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="games/pythagoreantable.html"><img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="pythagoreantable"></a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 class="gametitle">Pythagorean Table</h3>
        <h2>Tool</h2>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible CSS method within your HTML structure to change `.caption` when hovering `img`,  because `img` is one level lower and there is no parent selector.

But `img` is wrapped in an `a` tag, and `a` is a sibling of `.content`, so you can use a sibling selector:

```
li a:first-child + .caption
```

And for hovering:

```
li a:first-child:hover + .caption
```

I added `li` and `:first-child` to  only select those `a` elements in your code which contain `img` with class `.img`. But that's not 100% reliable (there could be a similar structure somewhere else in the document), so it would be better if you use a class on those `a` tags and use that class in your selector to clearly exclude any other `a` tags.

```css
.img {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  border-radius: 85px;
}

.img:hover {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.3) translate(0px, -80px);
  z-index: 100;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.525);
  border-radius: 85px;
}

li a:first-child + .caption {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -150px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

li a:first-child:hover + .caption {
  transform: scale(1.3) translate(0px, 40px);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="games/tictactoe.html"><img id="picture" class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="TicTacToe"></a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 class="gametitle">Tic Tac Toe</h3>
        <h2>Game for two players</h2>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="games/battleship.html"><img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="battleShip"></a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 class="gametitle">Battle Ship</h3>
        <h2>Game for two players</h2>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="games/pythagoreantable.html"><img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="pythagoreantable"></a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 class="gametitle">Pythagorean Table</h3>
        <h2>Tool</h2>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```